# XML Tree-viewer for large data sets?

Tags: xml

I'm looking for an application that will display the XML schema for large (between 40-300MB in filesize) sets of data. Obviously, the built in viewers for major browsers fail at loading the data. Notepad++ and the like can't handle the data and either crash or freeze for 5 minutes when I try to scroll, and every standalone application I've tried, like TreeViwer has frozen or crashed before loading the data.

Are there any XML-viewing tools that can handle such large datasets? I'd prefer anything available for windows.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/308679/lightweight-xml-viewer-that-can-handle-large-files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was recommended [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/308679/lightweight-xml-viewer-that-can-handle-large-files), which has more relevant information for you.

[Free XML editor](http://www.firstobject.com/dn_editor.htm)

Comment: This works absolutely perfectly. It's exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

XMLMax Viewer is a free xml tree viewer with no file size limit. From xponensoftware.

Author is affiliated with the vendor.

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser. While we appreciate you acknowledging you are part of the project, can you give a blurb about it, a link, and maybe a bit more information about it?